# the callback function delay of Hrtimer

Tags: delay

I write a linux module which start a hrtimer and it's callback function called every 20us. Assume the start time is 0,then the execute time of the callback function should be 20us, 40us, 60us，……， But In my program ,the result is that in some cases, the executing of the callback function may be delayed for a long time. I am wondering why this happened.

my module are running on x86_64 platform and the tsc is used to calculate the delay. The following is my code:

```c
static enum hrtimer_restart hwt_timer_fn(struct hrtimer *timer) {
    unsigned long long tick_start;

    rdtscll(tick_start);
    tick_err = tick_start - cmp_cycle;
    cmp_cycle += tick_cycle;                //cmp_cycle means the next execute time of the callback function 
    hrtimer_add_expires(timer, expires);

    count++;
    if(tick_err > max_err)
            max_err = tick_err;
    if(tick_err < min_err)
            min_err = tick_err;

    return HRTIMER_RESTART;
}

static int kthread_hrtimer(void *arg) {
    struct timespec val;
    unsigned long long tick_start;

    val.tv_sec = 0;
    val.tv_nsec = 20*1000;
    expires = timespec_to_ktime(val);

    count = 0;
    max_err = min_err = 0;
    tick_cycle = cpu_khz/50;        //the tsc cycle of 20us
    printk("cpu_freq:%u,tick_cycle:%llu\n",cpu_khz,tick_cycle);

    hrtimer_init(&timer, CLOCK_REALTIME, HRTIMER_MODE_ABS);
    timer.function = hwt_timer_fn;

    rdtscll(tick_start);
    hrtimer_start(&timer,expires,HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
    cmp_cycle = tick_start + tick_cycle;

    return 0;
}

int hwt_timer_init(void) {
    cpumask_t mask;

    cpus_clear(mask);
    cpu_set(0,mask);

    thread = kthread_create(kthread_hrtimer,NULL,"kthread_hrtimer");
    if(IS_ERR(thread))
    {
            printk("create failure\n");
            return 1;
    }
    set_cpus_allowed_ptr(thread,&mask);
    wake_up_process(thread);

    return 0;
}

void hwt_timer_exit(void) {
    while(hrtimer_try_to_cancel(&timer) < 0);
    printk("max_err:%lld,min_err:%lld\n",max_err,min_err);
    printk("count:%lld\n",count);
    printk("\n\n");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, Linux is not a hard real-time OS. While hrtimers are guaranteed to fire after their set target has elapsed and not before, there are no guaranteed bounds on the response time. Specifically, the hrtimers mechanism does not guarantee the amount of time that elapses between when the target time occurs and when the timer fires.

One possible reason that a firing might be delayed is that the kernel may be in a critical section that involves disabling interrupts. In that case, the timing interrupt that would lead to your hrtimer function being called is masked until the kernel exits the critical section and enables interrupts again.

To address the first problem of a one-sided timer guarantee, I would recommend the following:

- Use a threshold value, lets call it TIMER_THRESHOLD
- When setting up the timer for a target time, set the actual target slightly earlier.
  (for example, instead of using "expires" use "expires - (TIMER_THRESHOLD/2)")
- Inside the timer callback, check the "current time" against the "target time" and assume that the target time is reached if the "current time" is within TIMER_THRESHOLD of the target time.

Also, for periodic timing events, I would recommend using hrtimer_forward_now rather than hrtimer_add_expires. The reason is to handle the case where the timer missed its deadline by more than the timer period. In that case, hrtimer_add_expires still sets a target thats in the past.

Lastly, the other suggestion I have is to use a longer delay than 20us if possible. 20us is a very short period of time. On a GHz processor, thats in the order of 20000 instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I support Safayet Ahmed's answer. I want to add some comments anyway.

Check the CONFIG_HZ option on your system, usually the CONFIG_HZ is 1000. That means the system timer precision can be around 1ms(usually better than 1ms, but can not reach the "us" precision).

Try to change the CONFIG_HZ to a larger value to check your hrtimer precision is improved or not. If not, please check the hrtimer APIs. Maybe the issue is related to your misusage of the hrtimer APIs.